# Why didn't they just kill the young looper?

Tags: looper

In the movie Looper at the start there is a looper from the future that is sent to the past to be killed but manages to escape. The mafia then captures the present form of the looper and start torturing him to lure the future looper to them so they could kill him.

Why didn't they just kill the present looper immediately? They ended up doing this anyways, and this would have caused the future looper to disappear like we saw at the end of the movie